# index of non "NaN" values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

From Pandas data frame, how to get index of non "NaN" values?

My data frame is

```
    A    b     c
0   1    q1    1
1   2    NaN   3
2   3    q2    3
3   4    q1    NaN
4   5    q2    7
```

And I want the index of the rows in which column **b** is not NaN. (there can be NaN values in other column e.g. c )

> non_nana_index = [0,2,3,4]

Using this non "NaN" index list I want to create new data frame which column **b** do not have "Nan"

df2=

```
    A    b     c
0   1    q1    1
1   3    q2    3
2   4    q1    NaN
3   5    q2    7
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just filter them

```
In [62]:

df['b'].notnull()

Out[62]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
In [63]:

df[df['b'].notnull()]
Out[63]:
   A   b   c
0  1  q1   1
2  3  q2   3
3  4  q1 NaN
4  5  q2   7
```

Answer (score 14):

DataFrames have a `dropna` method:

```
import pandas
import numpy

d = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, numpy.nan], 
                      'b': [1, 2, numpy.nan, 3],
                      'c': [1, numpy.nan, 2, 3]})
d.dropna(subset=['b'])
```

Comment: `dropna`, will remove all the column or row, depending on the other arguments. The OP was looking for the index of the `NaN`

Comment: @Kots when you read through the whole question you will see his actual ask was " I want to create new data frame which column b do not have "Nan"". He was just expecting to need the indexes of these rows to get there. My answer shows you can get there without the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here:

```
In [5]: df.query('b == b')
Out[5]: 
   A   b    c
0  1  q1  1.0
2  3  q2  3.0
3  4  q1  NaN
4  5  q2  7.0
```

This works as NaN when compared to itself returns *False*:

```
In [5]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[5]: False
```