# python pandas index of ones (1s) at row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

From Pandas Dataframe, how to get the index of all ones at the row level?

My data frame has around a hundred columns. here is an example:

```
    a    b     c    d
0   1    0     1    0
1   0    0     0    1
2   1    1     0    1
3   1    1     0    0
4   1    1     1    1
```

The expected result is

```
0   a,c
1   d
2   a,b,d
3   a,b
4   a,b,c,d
```

I found this question on stackoverflow 
[index of non "NaN" values in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511200/index-of-non-nan-values-in-pandas?rq=1)
 but it works at the column level

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question's title says something `NaN`, but there is no `NaN` in your sample.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i just considered 0s as being NaN for me.

Comment: I corrected the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only `1` and `0` values use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication with columns names and separator, last remove separator with [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['e'] = df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
#if exist another values like 0,1 and compare 1
#df['e'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
   a  b  c  d           e
0  1  0  1  0        a, c
1  0  0  0  1           d
2  1  1  0  1     a, b, d
3  1  1  0  0        a, b
4  1  1  1  1  a, b, c, d
```

Also for `Series` use:

```
s = df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (s)
0          a, c
1             d
2       a, b, d
3          a, b
4    a, b, c, d
dtype: object
```

Comment: It is giving me a Memory Error results. Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Number of columns is 152

Comment: Thanks it works now. it looks i had some issues with one of the columns. i removed that column

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df=df.stack()
df=df.loc[df.eq(1)].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Outputs:

```py
      level_1
0        a, c
1           d
2     a, b, d
3        a, b
4  a, b, c, d
```